# How to post x-www-form-urlencoded post request?

Tags: java

I am having troubles with posting http POST request in java. All the details are correct, but I am getting error for not valid API key.
I tried everything, and read every single post that I could find here but still no clue what is incorrect.
Here's the code:

```
String urlString = "https://example.com/";
                            url = new URL(urlString);
                            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                            String data = URLEncoder.encode("api_key", "UTF-8")
                                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("xxxxx", "UTF-8");

                            urlConnection.connect();
                            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                            wr.write(data);
                            wr.flush();
                            try{
                                stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                                String result = reader.readLine();
                                System.out.println(result);
                                } catch (IOException e){
                                    throw(new Throwable("An error occured:\n" + e));
                            }
```

Comment: Well it seems that the API key you are providing is `xxxxx`... What is the correct API key?

Comment: I changed it only for purpose of displaying it here, the API key is good, as i checked it in postman

Comment: Is it possible to check what string is received at the API? It might be possible that the string is not decoded by the API.

Comment: It is not possible, as I am accessing public API

Comment: Which API? Perhaps there is some sample code in the docs that can help out as there does not seem to be much to go on here with the given details.

Comment: There's no sample code on their website, only API calls and params